# Create a new column in CSV based on contents of another

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I have a pipe delimited CSV with a URL in the 5th field and I'm looking to use an `awk` command to copy everything before a question mark character and add a new column with the contents.  The command I'm using currently is:

```
cat test.log | awk -F\| -v OFS=\| '{sub(/\?(.*)/,OFS "&", $7); print}' > test2.log
```

There are a few issues with this:

1. The regex in the current command is for finding everything AFTER the question mark.  The appropriate regex for finding everything before is /[^?]* however I'm getting a syntax error attempting to use that in the command.  I'm not as worried about this as I can likely sort it out with more testing.
2. The above command creates a new column with the data matching the regex, however it strips it from the column rather than copying it.

This is an example of what I'm looking for:

```
||||test.com|moredata|
||||test2.com?p1=1|moredata|
||||test3.com?p1=1&p2=2|moredata|
```

Becomes:

```
||||test.com|moredata|test.com
||||test2.com?p1=1|moredata|test2.com
||||test3.com?p1=1&p2=2|moredata|test3.com
```

Is there a function that behaves similarly without substituting that would be better suited for this (ie - match?)  Thanks in advance!

Comment: shouldn't it be `test2.com?p1=1|test2.com|`

Comment: Indeed.. was having issues with code tags and typed each line manually.  Thanks!

Comment: Post the code that's getting the error. It looks like you're just missing the `/` at the end of the regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split()` to split the URL at the `?` character, then you can get the part before this and append it.

```
awk -F\| -v OFS=\| '{split($5, url, "\?"); $5 = $5 OFS url[1]; print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of ways to get the output you want from the input you provided but using sub() does seem to be the simplest so idk why you'd want to try to avoid it:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$NF=$5; sub(/[?].*/,"",$NF)} 1' file
||||test.com|moredata|test.com
||||test2.com?p1=1|moredata|test2.com
||||test3.com?p1=1&p2=2|moredata|test3.com
```